# Need helping with date format in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I have one trouble, in html file i'm need to use date field, and filed him date from django.
Example my first field (correctly)

```
.datetimepicker({value:'{% now "Y-m-d H:i" %}',step:10});
```

In the next field, i must set mouth + 1, ho i can do this?

For example :

```
.datetimepicker({value:'{% now "Y-(m+1)-d H:i" %}',step:10});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the view (not in the template).

- Create 2 variables (1 corresponding to now, 1 corresponding to now+1month)
- Pass them to your template

In views.py

```
from datetime import datetime
def yourView(request):

    now_date = datetime.now()
    now_date_plus_1m = ... # I let you search how to to this :)

    return render_to_response('your_template.html',
        {
            'now_date': now_date,
            'now_date_plus_1m': now_date_plus_1m
        },
            RequestContext(request)
        )
```

In your template file:

`.datetimepicker({value:'{{ now_date|date:"Y-m-d H:i" }}',step:10});`
`.datetimepicker({value:'{{ now_date_plus_1m|date:"Y-m-d H:i" }}',step:10});`

Comment: Maybe i can use something from java-script?

Comment: Maybe django date i can replace javascript variable date?

Comment: No sure to understand what you want. What's wrong with the solution I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

The django template system is meant to express **presentation**, not program **logic** this why you should do your logic at the view level